# Maui How to show cursor as pointer on Windows?

Tags: maui, maui-windows

In a Maui app on Windows, I would like the **cursor to look like a pointer** while hovering over a Label with TapGestureRecognizer or a Button. **Is that possible and if so, how?**

All I have found so far is some alternative way of feedback through background color.

```xml
<PointerGestureRecognizer PointerEntered="OnPointerEntered"
                          PointerExited="OnPointerExited" />
```

and C#:

```cs
private void OnPointerEntered(object? sender, PointerEventArgs e)
{
    (((Label)sender!)!).BackgroundColor = Colors.LightCyan;
}

private void OnPointerExited(object? sender, PointerEventArgs e)
{
    (((Label)sender!)!).BackgroundColor = Colors.White;
}
```

Comment: A quick [web search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=maui+windows+cursor&ia=web) yielded this: https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Setting-a-cursor-for-.NET-MAUI-VisualElement/

Comment: @Julian It looks pretty cool. But VisualElement does not have a method SetCustomCursor(..) (used in his class CursorBehavior), so it does not work.

Comment: I have not looked closely at code, but probably you have EITHER not correctly added **static class CursorExtensions** that defines `SetCustomCursor`, and adds it to `VisualElement`, OR have mixed up **cross-platform** `VisualElement` with a **platform-specific** class, which must be inside folder `Platforms/PlatformNameHere` or inside `#if PlatformNameHere`. To test the first case, see if intellisense can find `CursorExtensions.SetCustomCursor(.., ..)`, or complains it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code does work on my side. When debugging the code, click the `SetCustomCursor()` in `CursorExtensions.cs` and then go to its definition (enter F12), it directs to the `CursorExtensions.cs` in `Platforms/Android`. So you may need add that implementation in your Maui project.

Also, notice that the [namespace format](https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/blob/main/MauiCursor/Platforms/Windows/CursorExtensions.cs) is little difference compared to that you create a new class. You can download the [sample project](https://github.com/VladislavAntonyuk/MauiSamples/tree/main/MauiCursor) and then copy necessary file to your Maui Project. The only thing you need to do is changing the `namespace MauiCursor;` to your own proejct namespace `namespace yourownproject;`